# expect static call with some certain result

Tags: java, powermock

I've got some static call of the system function in my method

`long currentDateMilliSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis();`

How to test this call and set some specific result for it using powermock?

I mean something like this

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
expectLastCall().andReturn(leftBound); // I expect to return some certain amount of milliseconds
```

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic. But I highly recommend to refactor your code and extract the role of a _time giver_ into an appropriate interface, for which one implementation could return the system's current time millis. The unit test then can simply use a mock of that interface.

Comment: Yup. I've used MockStatic to solve the problem. As for refactoring...Basically this call is in my own `DateUtils` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...I've done like this

```
mockStatic(System.class);
expect(System.currentTimeMillis()).andReturn(rightBound.getTime());
replayAll();
assertTrue(DateUtils.isInRange(leftBound, rightBound));
verifyAll();
```